# Chrome error "you are using an unsupported command-line flag: --ignore-certificate-errors."

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

I am using Coded UI for testing my web application on Chrome.  I am using the Cross Browser support offered by Coded UI.

I am using the below versions -

Visual Studio: 2013

selenium dotnet bindings: 2.43

When I start the web application in Chrome with BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "Chrome", the chrome browser opens with the popup - "you are using an unsupported command-line flag: --ignore-certificate-errors. ...".

I found some suggestions on web but those seem to be for those who are directly using Selenium.

But, they do not seem to be applicable here as I am using Coded UI.

Can anyone tell me how do I address this problem?

Regards,
kvk1985

Comment: At the end of the day, the way to get past this is to pass the argument `--test-type` in addition to `--ignore-certificate-errors`

Answer (score 1):

Please use below code, it worked me...

```
  IWebDriver driver;
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArguments("--disable-extensions");
        options.AddArgument("test-type");
        options.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors");
        options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://ahn-qa2.aon.com/home.aspx");
```

Comment: Please do explain your answer too.

Comment: only `--test-type` is needed, see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36746675/10440128)

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue in Visual Studio 2013 Premium Update 4. 
The latest version of chromedriver.exe (2.12) addressed the issue for us.

1. Download the applicable zip from the 2.12 directory at http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
2. Right click on the downloaded zip file.
3. Select "properties".
4. Under "General" tab, click on the "Unblock" button.
5. Now unzip both the files and copy the contents to the following path.  Copy over the existing version of chromedriver.exe

"%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\microsoft shared\VSTT\Cross Browser Selenium Components" (for 32 bit machines)

"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Common Files\microsoft shared\VSTT\Cross Browser Selenium Components" (for 64 bit machines)

Launch Chrome with BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "Chrome" again, the message should be gone.

Comment: Thanks, with chromedriver 2.12, the issue is not seen.