# Chrome Error: You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --ignore-certifcate-errors. Stability and security will suffer

Tags: java, google-chrome, testing, selenium-webdriver

Browser opens with the below mentioned line-

> You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --ignore-certifcate-errors. Stability and security will suffer.

as well as after few second the browser close and the error is thrown.

I am facing the above error when i run my code on chrome.

I am using chrome version - 44.0.2403.155 and latest selenium jars.

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Well, are you using that flag?

Comment: The solution is to not use that command line flag because it's unsupported

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass driver ChromeOptions and DesiredCapabilities?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23834413/pass-driver-chromeoptions-and-desiredcapabilities)

Comment: Note: if you actually want to ignore invalid certificates there's an option you can enable in chrome: `Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost` in `chrome://flags`

Comment: Thanks for your answer....the issue which i was facing problem was due to the exe which i was using for chrome I downloaded the latest from

Comment: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads and it started working

Comment: Thanks.. Life saver

Comment: You have typo: certifcate -> certificate

Answer (score 19):

You can add this to the shortcut of the chrome browser, in the Target portion:

```
–-test-type
```

This would disable any warning messages.
Not the best solution, but it works.

Comment: This literally suppressed the on-start warning messages in Chromium. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, worked. For me, it was the "`extensions-on-chrome-urls`" flag that caused it. I don't even know why it warns about that, there's a warning on chrome://flags about all the flags anyway. I only have two extensions and trust both of them.

Comment: where exactly do I have to add this : I have a location "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

Comment: @Kmayur7777 wherever you have he startup script

Comment: It should be `--test-type`

Answer (score 10):

For a chrome version of `58.0.3029.110`, You should use Chrome.driver of `2.28 version`. Download driver from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.28/

Note: If you want to download other `chromedriver of other version` then `change version number` in the above url.

`Happy learning`

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @GhostCat for Chrome 44.0.2403.155, try with http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.25/  or lesser vesion driver. hope your issue will get resolved. :)

Comment: My comment was meant to explain why link only answers are discouraged. That is all I wanted to say.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue recently. I found out I was using a 32-bit chromedriver for a 64-bit Mac. So I simply replaced the chromedriver with a 64-bit chromedriver from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.25/ and the error was gone.

Comment: i have same issue i change other version of chromedriver and it works for me.and note that chrome driver don't have 64bit version .but good thing is that 32bit work on both 64 and 32 bit window.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this on Windows by opening the properties of the Chrome shortcut. There I deleted the `--ignore-certificate-errors` flag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code  when you create driver. I hope it will help:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
setDefaultCapabilities(capabilities);
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--ignore-certificate-errors"));
options.addArguments(Arrays.asList("allow-running-insecure-content", "ignore-certificate-errors"));
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use chromedriver 2.12 version (chromedriver_win32.zip) from the path  http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.12/

You wont see this pop up.

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless 
if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site 
just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy 
the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing 
your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always 
leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your 
material...

Answer (score 0):

If your browser the latest version try with the latest chrome driver. I got the same issue but when changed it to the latest driver and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to chrome driver incompatibility with chrome browser. 
1.Uninstall chrome driver.
2.Check the chrome browser version you are using.
3.Find a corresponding compatible chrome driver( browser version compatible) and install it.
Do not forget to restart the system after step 1 and step 3.
I think this should fix the issue. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue so while the following code i added as ChromeOptions helped me resolve this is just as @Pritam Banerjee said

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\chromedriver.exe");
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver"));
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.addArguments("no-sandbox");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--test-type");// this is the one that helped
    chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-extensions");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    System.out.println("Google is selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

Mine had the same error because of chrome remote desktop. I removed it From my programs and I no longer get the error

Comment: Hi Jennifer, please post this as a comment on the question, as this is not very specific and detailed.  Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer  to get more clarity.