# Error when I am deploying my google cloud endpoints python application in localhost with App Engine SDK

Tags: python, google-chrome, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I use the google cloud endpoints configuration as

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/test_deploy

exactly, I run google chrome with flag

```
--user-data-dir=temp --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://localhost:8080
```

as

https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/#hitting_local_api

then, Google Chrome say me

> You are using an unsupported command-line
>   (--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure) flag. Stability and
>   security will suffer

If I visit

_http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/explorer

then I get the error:

> The API you are exploring is hosted over HTTP, which can cause
>   problems. Learn how to use Explorer with a local HTTP API .

I try to add `--test-type` flag as

_http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32042187/chrome-error-you-are-using-an-unsupported-command-line-flag-ignore-certifcat

then google chrome dont say anything, but when I visit

_http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/explorer

I get the same error.

my app works fine in localhost except the endpoints part, and all works fine in appspot.com (endpoints too)

I use the last version of:

- Python 2.7.11
- App Engine SDK 1.9.35
- Google Chrome 49.0.2623.110

thank you and sorry for my english

Comment: I have the same problem on both windows 7 and windows 10.

Answer (score 5):

1. Click the shield button in Chrome's url bar.

[image: Chrome Google Cloud Endpoints API Explorer: load scripts]

2. Click "Load unsafe scripts".
3. Click services (on the left bar) to reload the page.

Comment: This works perfect. Thank you for the picture. I have read about this solution but I could not find the shield.

Comment: For (3), you mean on the **left** bar?

Answer (score 1):

I tried troubleshooting this issue when it first started happening for me. I quickly gave up and decided to just use another browser for the API explorer on localhost. IE 11 works for me. This isn't a great answer, but if you have other browsers installed, give them a try.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, IE11 on W10 shows the same error. I tried also Firefox 47.0 result is the same, Microsoft Edge shows nothing.

Comment: Just to clarify, I still see the red banner than says `The API you are exploring is hosted over HTTP, which can cause problems` in IE. But unlike in Chrome, after I click past a warning or two, it still works.

Comment: It works for me. I have warning window displayed on the bottom with something like "It is shown only secure content". I have to press button "Show all content" and then works. There is also described solution for Chrome by @Alex but your tip is also good workaround.

Answer (score 0):

While Alex has the best answer, I'd just like to point out that this is only a problem with the API Explorer (which can definitely be handy).

But it doesn't affect direct calls to the API itself. So the URL below works fine without having to open a special sandbox chrome app or changing the script settings

```
localhost:8080/_ah/api/greeting/v1/greetings/1
```