# Google app engine API explorer on Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, google-chrome, google-app-engine, ubuntu, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to open API explorer on chromium browser for Ubuntu: `(localhost:8080/_ah/api/explorer)`
I got the : "The API you are exploring is hosted over http ..." error
I can see ways to solve the issue on Windows and MAC, but couldn't find how to solve it on Linux, Ubuntu.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you tried the solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36497816)?

Comment: Thanks, that worked