# Chromium headless remove --no-sandbox notification

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, headless, headless-browser

I am trying to run Chromium headless mode, with the following command:

```
chromium --no-sandbox \
        --kiosk \
        --disable-extensions \
        https://www.chromium.org
```

How can I get rid of that notification bar in the top?

[image]

Comment: `-test-type` flag does it as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32042187/chrome-error-you-are-using-an-unsupported-command-line-flag-ignore-certifcat).