# Web page in Chrome does not open with selenium in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below code opens a chrome tab but does not open the google link.

Error : "You are using an unsupported command-line flag"

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Chrome("E:\\Chrome Driver\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: the path should be with `r` prefix like `r"E:\\Chrome Driver\\chromedriver.exe"` instead of `"E:\\Chrome Driver\\chromedriver.exe"` .

The final statement should be like `driver=webdriver.Chrome(r"E:\\Chrome Driver\\chromedriver.exe")`

Comment: the backslashes might be the problem. Can you try `webdriver.Chrome("E:/Chrome Driver/chromedriver.exe")`

Comment: Put the driver in the same directory as your file, and no need to define the driver path.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to convert it to raw string but even after that same error shows up. Also, it also asks to disable the developer extension

Comment: Thanks. I tried to convert it to raw string but even after that same error shows up. Also, it also asks to disable the developer extension

Comment: replaced backslashes with forward slashes - no go @hansaplast

Answer (score -1):

go through this link. your code is perfect. it is only version problem
[Chrome Error: You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --ignore-certifcate-errors. Stability and security will suffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32042187/chrome-error-you-are-using-an-unsupported-command-line-flag-ignore-certifcat)

Comment: Yes, After installing chromedriver 2.34 it worked!. Thanks.